# Find the matrix of a particularly defined endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ endomorphism on $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $-1$ is the only eigenvalue and $B={v,u,w}$ is a basis such that $f(v)=-v$ and $f(u)=-u$. I see that this should be an automorphism (otherwise it should have had 0 as an eigenvalue, right?), but I don't understand how can I calculate the determinant of the matrix associated to $f$ with respect to the basis $B$. Can you show me?

Comment: That's not necessarily true @DiegoMath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe that since $-1$ is the only (real) eigenvalue,  if the the characteristic polynomial splits it is  $-(x-1)^3$. And yes it is an automorphism otherwise $0$ would be an eigenvalue.

Since $f(v)= - v$ and $f(u)= - u$ it follows that the dimension of the eigenspace associated to $-1$ is at least $2$. Consequently $(x-1)^2$ divides the characteristic polynomial, and the characteristic polynomial factors completely. So, it is thus equal to $-(x-1)^3$. The determinant is thus $(-1)^3 = -1$, that is the negative of the constant coefficient.

There is no unique matrix based on the information you give, but as we saw it is not needed to compute the determinant.

Indeed all one can say is that $f(w)= - w + av + b u$ for some reals $a,b$ or differently the matrix is relative to $(u,v,w)$ is

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 0  & b \\
0 & -1  & a \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Why is the characteristic polynomial $−(x−1)^3$ and it cannot be $(x−1)^3$?

Comment: Also, I don't understand this passage: "Consequently $(x−1)^2 $ divides the characteristic polynomial, and the characteristic polynomial factors completely". Why should it divide the ch. polynomial?

Comment: This is a matter of convention. Normally the characteristic polynomial is defined as $\det (A - x I) $ and thus the leading coeeficient is $(-1)^n$ where $n$ is the dimension. (Some also  have the convention to norm the char polynomial, in which case it would be what you say, yet then the determinant  is the constant coefficient, so  still $-1$.)

Comment: For you second question. Both $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors to $-1$ and they are independent as they are elements of a basis. Thus as said the eigenspace associated to $-1$ has dimension at least two. It is a general fact that the multiplicity of a root in a characteristic polynomial is an upper bound for the dimension of the eignespace.  Thus the multiplicity is at least $2$ which is just saying that $(x-1)^2$ divides the char polynomial.

Comment: No I am not concluding that it is gianonalizable. In general it is not diagonalizable. It is only diagonalizable if the $a,b$ above are both $0$. One cannot tell based on the information you gave if it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Perhaps I should also add that once you know that $(x-1)^2$ divisdes the fact that it splits is due to the quotient being of degree one and thus it has a root, which is an eigenvalue an thus must also be $-1$.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am glad the information was useful to you. I found the exercise curious as at first it seems some information is missing but then it works out.